# get the elements mouse is over for the html in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the elements that the mouse is over in an iframe?  The following code works for a HTML page but not the html in the iframe>

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javacsript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        $(document).ready(function ({
            $('body').mousemove(function (e) {
                var details = e.target.id;
                console.log(details);
            });
         });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="800" height="800" id="five"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Is the `<script>` tag in the listing twice by accident?

Comment: You can't if the iframe does not come from the same domain.

Comment: Major security issue here if you were allowed to do that in an iframe that is not on the same domain. Let think of an iframe that loads a financial website and get injected in order to redirect all the credentials to a mysterious person. Nasty... so you can't do that, unless you are also controlling that domain (see: same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set that code into the web page that you load in the `iframe`. That's because you are showing another web page into the `iframe`. Then, your main page and your `iframe` have their own CSS, JS, etc. If you don't want to add that code into your web page that is loaded into the `iframe`, you will have to access it using something like this:

```
//THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").removeClass("hidden");
```

For your example, I suggest to use this:

```
<script type="text/javacsript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/
    1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> //YOU FORGOT TO ADD THIS OPENING SCRIPT TAG
    $(document).ready(function({
        // THIS SHOULD WORK FOR YOUR MAIN PAGE
        $('body').mousemove(function (e) {
            var details = e.target.id;
            console.log(details);
        });
        // THIS SHOULD WORK FOR YOUR IFRAME
        $("#iFrame").contents().find.('body').mousemove(function (e) {
            var details = e.target.id;
            console.log(details);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Reference: **[Accessing Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: but it must be possible from the outer page?

Comment: so are you saying that I must inject the mouse move event and jquery? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hello-World I will update with an example that should work in your case. **Added example**

Comment: Aside from syntax errors, this would only work if the frame is from the same domain, which is not the case in the example.

Comment: @FelixKling That's true. I suggested this if it is from the same domain. If it is an external url that you don't manage like in the example (I supposed that url was just as an url example), you can't add your javascript mouse event to that web page, obviusly. That's why I posted that link to Stackoverflow, if someone wanted more information about accessing an Iframe and `Same origin policy`.